# Node app fails to push to Heroku

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, heroku

i am gettting this error
 Build failed
remote: parse error: Expected another key-value pair at line 53, column 3
remote: parse error: Expected another key-value pair at line 53, column 3
remote: parse error: Expected another key-value pair at line 53, column 3
Here is a section my **package.json**line 53 is the curly braces  just before the engines

```
"devDependencies": {

"@angular/language-service": "^5.2.0",
"@types/jasmine": "~2.8.3",
"@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
"@types/node": "~6.0.60",
"codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
"jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
"karma": "~2.0.0",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
"karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
"karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
"protractor": "~5.1.2",
"ts-node": "~4.1.0",
"tslint": "~5.9.1"

}

"engines": {
"node" : "8.10.0",
"npm" : "5.6.0"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you're just missing a comma on line 53

```
{
  "devDependencies": {

  "@angular/language-service": "^5.2.0",
  "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.3",
  "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
  "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
  "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
  "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
  "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
  "karma": "~2.0.0",
  "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
  "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
  "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
  "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
  "protractor": "~5.1.2",
  "ts-node": "~4.1.0",
  "tslint": "~5.9.1"

  },

  "engines": {
  "node" : "8.10.0",
  "npm" : "5.6.0"
  }
}
```